# Spring.net how to assign an enum value to property

Tags: c#, spring, enums

I've a class with the following property:

```
public class Animal
{    
     public AnimalTypeEnum AnimalType { get; set; }
}
```

and this following enum:

```
public enum AnimalTypeEnum 
{
      Dog = 0,
      Cat = 1,
      Bird = 2,
}
```

And i'd like to initiate an instance of my class via Spring.Net configuration file, in the following manner:

```
 <object id="MyAnimal" type="MyProg.Animal , MyProg">    
      <property name="AnimalType" expression="MyProg.AnimalTypeEnum.Dog"/>
 </object>
```

So far I've little success to evaluate AnimalType.Dog, I've tried numerous ways, 
any idea?

The error message i'm getting: Cannot initialize property or field node 'MyProg' because the specified context is null

Comment: Shouldn't it be <property name="AnimalType" expression="AnimalTypeEnum.Dog"/>?

Comment: Now that you've clarified your expression...  What happens when you try to inflate it?

Comment: The error message i'm getting:
Cannot initialize property or field node 'MyProg' because the specified context is null.

Comment: Besides the fact that you need to update the question with that error message, it looks like the error is not with the enum as you stated, but with the context "MyProg".  Your question and the code you listed are leading everyone down the wrong path to resolve this issue

Comment: Taegost, I've added the error message, the question remains the same, can you provide any actual wisdom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the answer at the most obvious place, spring.net web site

according the [documentation](http://springframework.net/docs/1.3.2/reference/pdf/spring-net-reference.pdf) (and it works!)

all you have to do is simply specify the enum value like the following:

```
<object id="MyAnimal" type="MyProg.Animal , MyProg">    
  <property name="AnimalType" value="Dog"/>
</object>
```